# How to close MUI Modal opened from parent component inside child component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I need to build a modal component that is opened from a parent component and closed from the modal component itself in React.

I'm setting the state in the parent component and passed it down to the child modal component as props:

```
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleOpenFromParent = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(true)
  }

  const handleCloseFromChild = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(false)
  }
```

and

```
      <div
        className={`${styles.w_30} p-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column`}
        onClick={handleOpenFromParent}
      >
        <ModalPaymentMethods
          playerNickname={nickname}
          paymentDescription={paymentMethodsVisa}
          paymentLogo={<Icon icon='mdi:credit-card-outline' color={'#84c3d3'} style={{ fontSize: '150px' }} />}
          depositTimes={11}
          depositAmount={'€18.6k'}
          depositTimesLastSixMonths={9}
          depositQuantityLastSixMonths={'€12.7k'}
          paymentMethodNumber={4301165517084005}
          expiryMonth={'07'}
          expiryYear={'2017'}
          holderName={`${name + ' ' + lastName}`}
          billingAddress={address}
          modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
          handleCloseFromChild={handleCloseFromChild}
        />
      </div>
```

I have no problems in opening the modal from the parent, but I'm not managing to close it once opened, from the child component.

I'm passing a callback `handleCloseFromChild` as a prop to set the visibility state back to false on the modal but it's not working, `modalIsOpen` remains always true and is never set to false from the callback function:

```
const ModalPaymentMethods = ({
  playerNickname,
  paymentDescription,
  paymentLogo,
  depositTimes,
  depositAmount,
  depositTimesLastSixMonths,
  depositQuantityLastSixMonths,
  paymentMethodNumber,
  expiryMonth,
  expiryYear,
  holderName,
  billingAddress,
  modalIsOpen,
  handleCloseFromChild
}) => {
  console.log(modalIsOpen)
  console.log(handleCloseFromChild)

  return (
    <div className={styles.ModalPaymentMethods}>
      <Modal
        open={modalIsOpen}
        onClose={handleCloseFromChild}
        aria-labelledby='modal-modal-title'
        aria-describedby='modal-modal-description'
      >
       test
      </Modal>
     </div>
   )
```

Comment: Looking at the code in the parent, it appears **handleOpenFromParent** is triggered by clicking on the DIV that contains the child. If the action taken on the Modal to close it requires clicking on it, wouldn't this trigger the **handleOpenFromParent** onClick event handler in the parent DIV? If so,, every click in the Modal would reset **modalIsOpen** to **true**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `ModalPaymentMethods` component inside the div element which has `onClick` event.
Just try write console log on both `handleOpenFromParent` and `handleCloseFromChild` function, then you can find the problem.

You can simply solve that problem by using `stopPropagation` method.

```
const handleCloseFromChild = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   setModalIsOpen(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a open state like this:
`const [open,setOpen]=useState(false)`

After that define a function to handle it:
`const handleToggleModal=()=>{setOpen((current)=>!current)}`

and you should pass this `handleToggleModal` function as props to the child component and call it everywhere you need to close the modal.

`open` state is used as a toggle boolean value to close and open the modal